# How to indicate if mouse down event occurred on the horizontal or on vertical border side?

Tags: javascript, css

I create border that wraps iframe element:

```
<div id = "propertyArea" class="propertyArea" onmousedown="return StartResizingPropertiesWindow(event)" >
   <iframe id="PropertyCtrl" name="PropertyCtrl" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

On div(border) I have `onmousedown` event called StartResizingPropertiesWindow.
Inside event function I need to indicate if mouse down event occurred on the horizontal or on vertical border side.

Any idea how can I indicate if mouse down occured on the horizontal or on vertical border side?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which returns where you clicked on the border. Just make sure you replace the number `5` with the width of your border. --- If its of any help

```js
var elo = document.getElementById('outside');

elo.onmousedown = function(e) {

  detectSide(e);

};

function detectSide(e) {


  var X = e.pageX - elo.offsetLeft;
  var Y = e.pageY - elo.offsetTop;

  if (X < 5) {
    alert('left');
  }
  else if (X > elo.offsetWidth - 5) {
    alert('right');
  }
  else if (Y > elo.offsetHeight - 5) {
    alert('down');
  }
  else if (Y < 5) {
    alert('top');
  }
  //alert(Y);

}
```

```css
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="outside">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```